# Javascript RegEx to highlight a phrase match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have written a regular expression to highlight the matched phrase in a text by adding a span around the phrase. The text may contain `<b>` and `</b>` anywhere in the text and phrase is to be matched ignoring it.
Following is my code:

```
var phraseArray = phrase.split(" ");
var phraseRegex = "";
if (phraseArray.length > 1) {
    var regexSuffix = '+([/\\s]|<\/b>|<b>)+';
    for (var i = 0; i < phraseArray.length; i++) {
        phraseRegex += phraseArray[i] + regexSuffix;
        if (i == phraseArray.length - 2) {
            regexSuffix = "";
        }
    }
} else {
    phraseRegex = phrase;
}
text = text.replace(new RegExp('(' + '([,\\s]|<\/b>|<b>)+' + phraseRegex + '([\\s/,.*]|<\/b>|<b>)+' + ')', 'gi'), '<span class="highlighted">&nbsp;$1&nbsp;</span>');
```

If phrase is `Airways Aviation` and text is:

```
>    <b>Airways Aviation</b>. Airways Aviation  .Airways Aviation.  fra 
> Jet Airways.  Jet Airways (India A range of talented people make it
> happen every day at Airways Aviation, .
```

Following is the output:

```
<span class="highlighting"> <b>Airways Aviation</b>.</span> Airways Aviation  .Airways Aviation.  fra 
> Jet Airways.  Jet Airways (A range of talented people make it
> happen every day at<span class="highlighting"> Airways Aviation, .</span>
```

Second occurrence of Airways Aviation is not highlighted. What is the reason and how can it be enhanced?

Comment: what is your question? Is it not working or are you asking for enhancement to your code?

Comment: It is not working. What could be the reason and how can it be enhanced?

Comment: @ManojSuthar check the answer your question is not clear. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [EDIT based on your question edit]
>   [EDIT based on comment]

You have to use the `g` flag for Global Match.

- get the `word` to be matched
- create a new RegExp with adding
   `"(<b>)?"+word+"(</b>)?"` //may or maynot contain `<b>` and `</b>` at start and end, `g` for match all
- replace the above regex with span
- $& add the match

```js
var str="<b>Airways Aviation</b>. Airways<b> Aviation</b>  .Airways Aviation.  fra Jet Airways.  Jet Airways (India A range of talented people make ithappen every day at Airways Aviation, ."
 
 function test(word){
  word=word.split(" ").join("(<b>|</b>|\\s)*");
  var re=new RegExp("(<b>)?"+word+"(</b>)?",'g');
  console.log(str.replace(re,"<span class=\"highlighting\">$&</span>"));
}
test("Airways Aviation");
```

Working model

```js
function test(word){
  word=word.split(" ").join("(<b>|</b>|\\s)*");
  var re=new RegExp("(<b>)?"+word+"(</b>)?",'g');
  var str=document.getElementById('div');
  str.innerHTML=str.innerHTML.replace(re,"<span class=\"highlighting\">$&</span>");
}
```

```css
span.highlighting{
  background-color:#ccc;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="div"><b>Airways Aviation</b>. Airways<b> Aviation</b>  .Airways Aviation.  fra Jet Airways.  Jet Airways (India A range of talented people make ithappen every day at <b>Airways</b> Aviation, .</div>
<button onclick="test('Airways Aviation');">Change</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it fails for " <b>Airways</b> Aviation ". bold tag can occur anywhere in the phrase. Any word or subphrase of the phrase can be inside bold

Comment: Thank you very much Sagar. :) One more case that can happen is, if phrase is Air-ways Aviation and text contains Air-<b>ways</b> Aviation. How can that be included?